# Alternate for loop with hasmap in java

Tags: java, for-loop, hashmap

I have a for each loop running as:

```
for (System system : val.keySet()) 
{
   do something
}
```

Is there an alternate method to write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some ways how you can loop through a `map`:

**1- Using for-Each loop:**

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

**2- Iterating over keys or values**

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

//iterating over keys only
for (Integer key : map.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key = " + key);
}

//iterating over values only
for (Integer value : map.values()) {
    System.out.println("Value = " + value);
}
```

**3- Using `iterator`:**

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); 
Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> entries = map.entrySet().iterator(); 

while (entries.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = entries.next();
    System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue()); 
}
```